# IBM DB2 9.7 Error code 840, select statement list is too large

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

We are using Hibernate with IBM DB2 9.7. The database gives error about Hibernate generated too large select statement list (including a lot of joins). The error code is 840. Can something be done to fix this? I know the generated select list is very long, but can Hibernate be set to split it into parts or something?

Edit: I reopened this since the problem seems to be a bit larger. So there is a JIRA issue (now rejected) at https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-140.

So the problem is that with Hibernate Annotations, it is not possible to add discriminator with Join strategy. XML configuration however does support this.

Pavel nicely states the problem in the above link discussion like this:

```
"It would be nice to see how the problem with the multiple joins is faced when the
 underlying DB has restriction on the number of joins one can execute in a single SQL?
For instance MySQL seems to allow only 31 joins. What happens if the class hierarchy
has more     than 31 sub-classes?"
```

An the above is the very problem I am having. We are using annotations and the subclasses are quite a few, creating massive amounts of joins, breaking the DB2 statement.

Any comments on this? I could not find a direct solution either.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate has few fetching strategies to optimize the Hibernate generated select statement, so that it can be as efficient as possible. The fetching strategy is declared in the mapping relationship to define how Hibernate fetch its related collections and entities.

Fetching Strategies
There are four fetching strategies

1. fetch-”join” = Disable the lazy loading, always load all the collections and entities.
2. fetch-”select” (default) = Lazy load all the collections and entities.
3. batch-size=”N” = Fetching up to ‘N’ collections or entities, *Not record*.
4. fetch-”subselect” = Group its collection into a sub select statement.

For detail explanation, you can check on the [Hibernate documentation](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies).

Comment: A quick comment on this. So does it mean that with varying strategies (1-4) it is possible to reduce the select statement size? Note that I am not talking about that too many rows are returned, but that the actual select statement is too large with too many columns and joins.